# Java equation parsing for 1.2

Tags: java, parsing, equation-solving

For implementation specific reasons, I have to use Java 1.2. I am trying to parse a `String` object with only numbers (I replace variables beforehand to abstract that step) and operators (PEDMAS). I have found a lot of libraries that do this well, but unfortunately nothing that is compatible with Java 1.2 (Even with fiddling, all of them are dependent on things like generics). Obviously I'm capable of making this myself, but I would certainly prefer to not remake the wheel. Are there any libraries that I just haven't found yet that could do this for me? Thanks.

(Requirements: Binary operators and parentheses)

EDIT: As requested, some examples of input and output:

- "(10 / 5) + 4.5 - (8)" would give you -1.5
- "(1/3) * 4" would give you 1.3333333...
- "5^3 + 4 * 2" would give you 133
- "-10 + 5" would give you -5

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Can you give more info on what you're trying to do? Give some examples of input and expected output.

Comment: Made an edit with some examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). This Java [implementation](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/enumerated-functions) uses `StreamTokenizer`, available since 1.0, but you'll have to substitute `int` constants for the `enum` tokens and ignore `tokenIs(Symbol.WORD)` for function identifiers.

Comment: Small problem I'm encountering... It uses the method `Enum.valueOf(class, String)`, and because `Function` is no longer an enum, it cannot be used. (Function does not extend Enum) _found on line 276_.

Comment: Also, it appears I cannot access the Enum class (Java ME). Is there a way to replicate the function of this method without Enum?

Comment: Unless you need functions, just eliminate handling `Symbol.WORD` in `factor()`. If you do, I think Apache Commons had a pre-1.5 alternative.